# Easiest way to write quick data to amazon kinesis stream?

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I have a kinesis stream, kinesis firehouse, and s3 connected and I want to test this out by writing data quickly to the kinesis stream. All the clients out there seem kind of complicated to setup. What is a quick way to write to my kinesis stream?

Any ideas? Is there something in the AWS console that's easy to use?

Answer (score 0):

For now, the AWS console doesn't have anything like that for AWS Kinesis.

You can simply use a **single AWS CLI command for AWS Kinesis** that is **put-record** to write data quickly on your AWS Kinesis stream.

Usage Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kinesis/put-record.html